# RecyclerView deleting item doesn't call OnScrollListener

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, onscrolllistener

There seems to be a lot of post on how one can scroll up for more posts and I have posted a question on this before: [Adding items to Endless Scroll RecyclerView with ProgressBar at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681905/adding-items-to-endless-scroll-recyclerview-with-progressbar-at-bottom)

However, I have a question on deleting items in a list on recyclerview.
You have an android app which fetches 5 items from the database server in a page.
As soon as it fetches it, you start deleting items one by one.

The list recyclerview scrolls up but the OnScrollListener is not called as you haven't really "scrolled".

How do I address this problem when I want to add on more items to my list as my delete start eliminating items from the top?

Comment: What about when you save how many items get deleted and when a specific count get reached you fetch new items and reset the counter? Would that be a solution?

Comment: I'm unsure as the scrollListener seems to keep track of the current page. The easiest would be to "mock" a call to the scrollListener but don't know how that could be done.

Comment: Calling `mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0,0);` will cause a call to `onScrollChanged()` and the `RecyclerView` will be invalidated.

Comment: @Simon Were you able to find solution to this?

Comment: I posted this question a long time ago ... but I would imagine you can build in logic where when the items on the screen is 5 or less and u want to delete an item, u can call the api to download the next page of items so that the list is increased before the deletion happens. That way u will always have more items to scroll downwards and trigger onscrolllistener.

Answer (score -1):

when deleting each item call

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

it works perfectly

Comment: It's not a solution. Say, I have 150 items and deleting at position 130, Why should I scroll to position 0?

Comment: 0 is just an example , its the position of the element