# RecyclerView Infinite Scroll listener being called twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that im trying to implement an infinite scroll feature into. The issue is, the code inside the if statements in the `OnScrolled` method is being executed twice. Heres my current code:

```
public abstract class InfiniteScroll extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

private int current_page = 1;

public InfiniteScroll(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
    mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        // End has been reached

        // Do something
        current_page++;
        Log.d("moreitems", "why is this being called twice?");
        loadMore(current_page);

        loading = true;
    }
}

public abstract void loadMore(int current_page);
}
```

This code was posted as an answer to a separate SO question, and other examples seem to function similar, but I still get the `loadMore()` method executing twice when reaching the bottom of the `RecyclerView`, and im not sure why.

Comment: use `LimearLayoutManager#findLast[Completely]VisibleItemPosition()` method

Answer (score 13):

it's getting called because when you loadMore items, onScrolled is called again.

> This callback will also be called if visible item range changes after a layout calculation. In that case, dx and dy will be 0.

so you could check 
`if (!loading && dy>0)`
as well

Comment: Btw, I've added it to the start of `onScrolled` so nothing will be executed, is there a reason you used it with the `!loading`?, I saw it can go with `!loading` as well but why to execute in-between code, is it ok I moved it upwards like: `if(dy <= 0) return;`, I mean I didn't saw any problem with my code but maybe you run into some rare cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    loading = true;
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                       current_page++;
                       Log.d("moreitems", "why is this being called twice?");
                       loadMore(current_page);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Where do you set loading back to `false` with this solution? Otherwise loading stays `true` and reaching the end of the list again wont trigger another load.

Comment: I have posted a sample code here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253695/recyclerview-load-more-with-progressbar-error/35254285#35254285

Comment: Add loading = false; in the loarmore() method (last line). You should make loading to false after all you stuffs were completed.

Answer (score -1):

I just met similar situation, while solution is quite different from the above answer.

In my case, I have a custom RecyclerViewFragment, which will set up RecyclerView at the beginning of data loading stuff. And I add a custom OnScrollListener at that set up method block.

My reason why OnScrollListener was called twice is, I accidently add two OnScrollListener to my RecyclerView. Thus these two listener will both listener to the "scroll to the end" action and do something for it.

So I just remove all the OnScrollListener for my RecyclerView before I call the set up method, to make sure that there will only be one OnScrollListener.

Hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 
recyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
     //load more items code is here
}
```

This will work.