# Endless RecyclerView - progress bar are not disappearing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView and fetching objects from an API in batches of ten. For pagination, I use EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener and following this tutorial [Endless RecyclerView](http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html). 
My problem: on scrolling programm adding progress bar and delete it after data from server fetched. But in my case it doesn't work. ProgressBar still downloading

[image: Endless RecyclerView]

Method that fetched data

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest(int startList,int endList,final JsonObjectListener listener) {
            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            i = startLsit;
                            while(i < endList) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                                  /***** TONS OF CODE  *****/

                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                              i++;
                              lastNumber = i;
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listener.onDone(lastNumber);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        }
```

Place where I use method:

```
 makeJsonObjectRequest(0, 9, new JsonObjectListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDone(int lastNumberI) {
                           lastNumber = lastNumberI;
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onError(String error) {

                       }
                   }); }

   mAdapter = new RVAdapter(getContext(),movieList,this,mRecyclerView);
        mAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                movieList.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(movieList.size()-1);
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        movieList.remove(movieList.size()-1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(movieList.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = lastNumber;
                        int end = start + 9;
                        makeJsonObjectRequest(start, end, new JsonObjectListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDone(int lastNumberI) {
                                lastNumber = lastNumberI;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(String error) {

                            }
                        });
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```

My adapter like this [Endless RecyclerView](http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html)

Comment: Is it Happening everytime?

Comment: @JacksonChengalai Yes, every time

Answer (score 1):

After getting response, you have to remove that null movie object and notify the adapter

```
 private void makeJsonObjectRequest(int startList,int endList,final JsonObjectListener listener) {
            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        movieList.remove(movieList.size()-1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(movieList.size());
                            i = startLsit;
                            while(i < endList) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                                  /***** TONS OF CODE  *****/

                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                              i++;
                              lastNumber = i;
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listener.onDone(lastNumber);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        }
```

Comment: I already do it there: 
                        movieList.remove(movieList.size()-1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(movieList.size());

Comment: after getting the response you should remove that view..Its working for me..Also check your getItemViewType in your recyclerview

Comment: I notice interesting things: when I scroll slowly progress bar desapire, but when I scroll faster it's remains. In debug I saw that when scrolling faster method onLoadMore repeats

Comment: this link will helpful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681905/adding-items-to-endless-scroll-recyclerview-with-progressbar-at-bottom?rq=1