# Android: How do I get a circular progressbar replaced with a message if no internet connection?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which is essentially endless, and it loads data 10 items at a time using a cursor. I got a circular progress bar to show up at the bottom when items are still loading, however, if I stop the internet connection, the progress bar continues to spin on forever. How would I implement a message that replaces the circular progress bar if there is no internet connection?

A good example of what I'm trying to do is what the Play Store uses, as well as reddit is fun.

[image: Progress bar while loading content]
(Progress bar while loading content)

[image: "No internet connection" message to replace progress bar]
("No internet connection" message to replace progress bar)

The code I used for my progress bar is very similar to the way @vilen implemented it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681905/adding-items-to-endless-scroll-recyclerview-with-progressbar-at-bottom)

Comment: Can you show the code for showing the progress bar. You should be able to do the same but to show a linear layout with the message.

Comment: Very similar to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681905/adding-items-to-endless-scroll-recyclerview-with-progressbar-at-bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the ProgressBar layout with another layout that has both the ProgressBar and a LinearLayout with the icon, message and retry button. In `onBindViewHolder`, show only progress bar if there is internet connection, otherwise only show the LinearLayout. In your activity, when you detect a change of internet connection, call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapter.getItemCount()-1)` to update the last item.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678314/5288316) for how to detect connectivity change.