# How to implement pagination in RecyclerView on scroll

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

`Recyclerview` comes with its own scroll listener which has the following methods :

```
void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
```

Callback method to be invoked when RecyclerView's scroll state changes.

```
void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
```

Callback method to be invoked when the RecyclerView has been scrolled.

Is there any way to trigger loader to load more data when scroll reaches end of the list?

> I have implemented this way:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    GenerItem generItem=generItems.get(i);
    Log.d("TAG","position "+i);
    if(i==generItems.size()-1)
    ((GenerSearchActivity)mContext).onScroll(i);
    viewHolder.bindValues(generItem);
}
```

Here `onScroll()` in Activity, will trigger the loader to load more data. What is the best way please suggest.

Comment: Is your method not working?

Comment: its working but i am not sure weather its a good way to proceed or is there any alternate  way to achieve this feature.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable approach!

Comment: Did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044449/put-an-indeterminate-progressbar-as-footer-in-a-recyclerview-grid

Comment: Thanks @YousefZakher it seems to work, i will try it.

Comment: If not i can past you sample of code, how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the support buddy, i will definitely ask you for code in case of failure ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Make Next Call at the end of scroll

[image]

There are essentially 3 steps.

1. Notify when the list is scrolled
2. Make REST call (for NEXT page)
3. Add the result in the old list + Notify DataSet change

### CALLBACK

But first, we need a Callback which would work as a bridge between RecyclerView.Adapter and Activity

```
public interface PaginationCallBack{
     public void oadNextPage();
}
```

> Implement this callback in Your Activity

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaginationCallBack{

     int pageNum = 1;

     @Override
     public void loadNextPage(){
           // Your implementation
     }
}
```

> Initialize Callback in RecyclerView.Adapter

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

     private PaginationCallBack paginationCallBack;

     public YourAdapter(PaginationCallBack paginationCallBack) {
        this.paginationCallBack = paginationCallBack;
     }

}
```

**STEP 1**
Add a condition in `onBindViewHolder` method and notify with a Callback.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {

    if(position+1==images.size()){
        paginationCallBack.loadNextPage();  // Callback
    }

}
```

**Step 2:** Call NEXT Page

getImages(++pageNum)  // YOUR REST method which page number

```
@Override
public void loadNextPage(){
    getImages(++pageNumber) // REST call with next Page 
}
```

**Step 3** Add the result in old list and notify datasetChanged

```
public void getImages(int pageNum){

      List<Images> newResults = //RESTCALL
      imageList.addAll(newResults);
      adapter.updateDataSet(imageList)

}
```

### Where is `updateDataSet(imageList)` method?

Write this method inside RecyclerView.Adapter

```
 public void updateDataSet(List<GalleryMedia> newImages){

    if(newImages!=null){
        images = newImages;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

### Full Code

[RecyclerView Pagination](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/RecyclerViewPagination)

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Usefull code.but how about the scoll down?

Comment: Would you elaborate? @SHemaNandhini

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scroll listener which implements load more and quick return pattern:

```
public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final float  HIDE_THRESHOLD   = 10;
    private static final float  SHOW_THRESHOLD   = 70;

    private int                 mToolbarOffset   = 0;
    private boolean             mControlsVisible = true;
    private int                 mToolbarHeight;
    private int                 mTotalScrolledDistance;
    private int                 previousTotal    = 0;
    private boolean             loading          = true;
    private int                 visibleThreshold = 4;
    int                         firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    public HidingScrollListener(Context context, LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        mToolbarHeight = Tools.getFooterHeight(context);
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (mTotalScrolledDistance < mToolbarHeight) {
                setVisible();
            }
            else {
                if (mControlsVisible) {
                    if (mToolbarOffset > HIDE_THRESHOLD) {
                        setInvisible();
                    }
                    else {
                        setVisible();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ((mToolbarHeight - mToolbarOffset) > SHOW_THRESHOLD) {
                        setVisible();
                    }
                    else {
                        setInvisible();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        clipToolbarOffset();
        onMoved(mToolbarOffset);

        if ((mToolbarOffset < mToolbarHeight && dy > 0) || (mToolbarOffset > 0 && dy < 0)) {
            mToolbarOffset += dy;
        }
        if (mTotalScrolledDistance < 0) {
            mTotalScrolledDistance = 0;
        }
        else {
            mTotalScrolledDistance += dy;
        }
        // for load more
        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached
            // Do something

            loading = true;
            onLoadMore();
        }
    }

    private void clipToolbarOffset() {
        if (mToolbarOffset > mToolbarHeight) {
            mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
        }
        else if (mToolbarOffset < 0) {
            mToolbarOffset = 0;
        }
    }

    private void setVisible() {
        if (mToolbarOffset > 0) {
            onShow();
            mToolbarOffset = 0;
        }
        mControlsVisible = true;
    }

    private void setInvisible() {
        if (mToolbarOffset < mToolbarHeight) {
            onHide();
            mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
        }
        mControlsVisible = false;
    }

    public abstract void onMoved(int distance);

    public abstract void onShow();

    public abstract void onHide();

    public abstract void onLoadMore();
}
```

And it's implementation is below:

```
HidingScrollListener scrollListener = new HidingScrollListener(activity, manager) {
         @Override
         public void onMoved(int distance) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onShow() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onHide() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadMore() {
            // you can do your pagination here.
         }
      };
      mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```