# How to use Android Pagination with Volley when fetching JSON data

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I am building an Android app that has a user comments page that may contain up to 1,000 comments. It won't be a good practice trying to fetch and load all the comments into the recyclerView all at once. So, I want an approach that will load the comments in batches, maybe 10 at a time, and when the user scrolls the recylcerView, it should load another 10 etc.

The problem is that I am using Volley to get the comments as JSON objects and I don't think Volley has batch processing. I am also not sure if some of the pagination would be done on my PHP file. I have watched several tutorials on Youtube and checked on Stack Overflow for answers including  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605487/is-there-any-way-to-load-5-10-items-in-recyclerview-at-a-time-instead-of-50k/40605562#40605562) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429347/how-to-implement-pagination-with-recyclerview-via-api-url-indexing)
But they don't really address my issue.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    define('DB_HOST','*******');
    define('DB_USER','********');
    define('DB_PASS','********');
    define('DB_NAME','***********');

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die('Unable to connect to database '.mysqli_connect_error());
    }

        $conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");

        $storyID = $_GET["storyid"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT comments_table.comment_id, comments_table.username, comments_table.comment, comments_table.date_time, comments_table.story_id, comments_table.imageURL, comments_table.number_of_likes, users.title, comments_table.is_reply, comments_table.reply_username, comments_table.reply_comment, comments_table.reply_id  FROM comments_table INNER JOIN users ON comments_table.username = users.username WHERE comments_table.story_id = '$storyID'");

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $username, $comment, $date_time, $story_id, $imageURL, $number_of_likes, $title, $is_reply, $reply_username, $reply_comment, $reply_id);

    $comments = array();

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['comment_id'] = $comment_id;
        $temp['username'] = $username;
        $temp['comment'] = $comment;
                $temp['date_time'] = $date_time;
                $temp['story_id'] = $story_id;
                $temp['imageURL'] = $imageURL;
                $temp['number_of_likes'] = $number_of_likes;
                $temp['title'] = $title;
                $temp['is_reply'] = $is_reply;
                $temp['reply_username'] = $reply_username;
                $temp['reply_comment'] = $reply_comment;
                $temp['reply_id'] = $reply_id;

        array_push($comments, $temp);

    }

    echo json_encode($comments);
```

This is the code snippet I used in retrieving the comments using Volley:

```
private void loadComments() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_COMMENTS + String.valueOf(storyID),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject comment = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                if (comment.getInt("story_id") == storyID) {
                                    commentList.add(new GetComments(
                                            comment.getInt("comment_id"),
                                            comment.getString("username"),
                                            comment.getString("comment"),
                                            comment.getInt("story_id"),
                                            comment.getString("imageURL"),
                                            comment.getString("date_time"),
                                            comment.getInt("number_of_likes"),
                                            comment.getString("title"),
                                            comment.getInt("is_reply"),
                                            comment.getInt("reply_id"),
                                            comment.getString("reply_username"),
                                            comment.getString("reply_comment")
                                    ));

                                }

                            }

                            if (commentList.isEmpty()){
                                noCommentTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            adapterJSON = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), commentList, Comment.this, rootView, storyID);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterJSON);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(Comment.this,"Error loading comments: Check internet connection...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(Comment.this,"Error loading comments: Check internet connection...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Comment.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        requestQueue.start();

        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
```

And these are my recyclerView and layoutManager imlementation:

```
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Any solution on how to achieve this or offering the right approach will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with pagination before with REST apis. 
But for your case, the easiest way is doing this:

When you make your first call to get the first 10, append the initial value 10 in your api parameter query like so https://example.com/index.php?limit=10;

In your php code, receive the value 'limit' and append this to your sql query like so :

> SELECT * from comments_table WHERE comments_table.story_id =
>   '$storyID' ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '$limit'

Check more under [LIMIT and OFFSET](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html)

This means your android app will keep a counter of sorts for the limit.
You can easily achieve this by:

```js
int limit = 10; //initial limit

//after success result from your api, just append a count
limit = limit + 10;
//and use this new limit in subsequent api calls to fetch comments
```

Most important is ofcourse tracking scrolling events to know if user reached end of the comments list, easily done by this user 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342525/4209724

Comment: Ok, let me try this and I'll get back. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Steve, you rock man. It worked like magic. I have battled this for a long time and I can move on to other things. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code as suggested by steve Kamau above. This is how I have modified my code:

My modified PHP code:

```
<?php

    define('DB_HOST','*******');
    define('DB_USER','*******');
    define('DB_PASS','******');
    define('DB_NAME','*********');

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die('Unable to connect to database '.mysqli_connect_error());
    }

        //mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4_unicode_ci");
        $conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");

        $storyID = $_GET["storyid"];
        $limit = $_GET["limit"];
        $offset = $_GET["offset"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT comments_table.comment_id, comments_table.username, comments_table.comment, comments_table.date_time, comments_table.story_id, comments_table.imageURL, comments_table.number_of_likes, users.title, comments_table.is_reply, comments_table.reply_username, comments_table.reply_comment, comments_table.reply_id  FROM comments_table INNER JOIN users ON comments_table.username = users.username WHERE comments_table.story_id = '$storyID' ORDER BY comments_table.date_time DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $username, $comment, $date_time, $story_id, $imageURL, $number_of_likes, $title, $is_reply, $reply_username, $reply_comment, $reply_id);

    $comments = array();

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['comment_id'] = $comment_id;
        $temp['username'] = $username;
        $temp['comment'] = $comment;
                $temp['date_time'] = $date_time;
                $temp['story_id'] = $story_id;
                $temp['imageURL'] = $imageURL;
                $temp['number_of_likes'] = $number_of_likes;
                $temp['title'] = $title;
                $temp['is_reply'] = $is_reply;
                $temp['reply_username'] = $reply_username;
                $temp['reply_comment'] = $reply_comment;
                $temp['reply_id'] = $reply_id;

        array_push($comments, $temp);

    }

    echo json_encode($comments);
```

I then initialised two Integer values:

```
int limit = 10;
int offset = 0;
```

Then I created an OnscrollListener for my recyclerView and created one more method to test if the user has scrolled to the last item:

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener endOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if(isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)){
                Log.i("Reached end: ", "Load more");
                loadMoreComments();
            }
        }
    };

    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        //Check if the adapter item count is greater than 0
        if(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0){
            //get the last visible item on screen using the layout manager
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if(lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
```

And finally, here is my loadMoreComments() method:

```
private void loadMoreComments() {
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_COMMENTS + String.valueOf(storyID)+"&limit="+String.valueOf(limit)
                +"&offset="+String.valueOf(offset),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject comment = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                if (comment.getInt("story_id") == storyID) {

                                    commentList.add(adapterJSON.getItemCount(), (new GetComments(
                                            comment.getInt("comment_id"),
                                            comment.getString("username"),
                                            comment.getString("comment"),
                                            comment.getInt("story_id"),
                                            comment.getString("imageURL"),
                                            comment.getString("date_time"),
                                            comment.getInt("number_of_likes"),
                                            comment.getString("title"),
                                            comment.getInt("is_reply"),
                                            comment.getInt("reply_id"),
                                            comment.getString("reply_username"),
                                            comment.getString("reply_comment")
                                    )));
                                    adapterJSON.notifyItemInserted(adapterJSON.getItemCount());
                                }


                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(Comment.this,"Error loading comments: Check internet connection...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("Error:", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(Comment.this,"Error loading comments: Check internet connection...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("Error:", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });


        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Comment.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        requestQueue.start();

        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                offset = offset + 5;
            }
        });

    }
```