# How to implement pagination in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am performing pagination in recyclerView. My data is loading successfully and problem is how can I request to server for the next page. How i can perform pagination and how i can find page number which is being scrolled.

My code is:

```
rvLatestProduct.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            //super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = rvLatestProduct.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.e("totalItemCount",String.valueOf(totalItemCount));
            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                   // currentPage += 1;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    Log.e("previousTotal",String.valueOf(previousTotal));
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                //int initialSize = totalItemCount.size;
                getPagination();
                //val updatedSize = dataList.size
              //  recyclerView.post { adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(initialSize, updatedSize) }
                loading = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

and getPagination(); code is given as

```
  private void getPagination(){
    final JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            AllURLs.viewAllLatestProduct,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                JSONArray object;
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                          object = response.getJSONArray(i);
                        }
                        setLatestProductAdapter(object);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       // Toast.makeText(context,"page no" + pageNo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
// Define variable in class 

private int page = 1, limit = 15;
private int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
private int previousTotal = 0;
private int visibleThreshold = 10;
```

**Code for recyclerView scroll listener:**

```
recyclerView
                .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx,
                        int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    if (dy > 0) {
                        mLinearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerLikedItemsList
                                .getLayoutManager();

                        if (!CheckInternet
                                .checkInternetConnection(AllLikedItemList.this)) {
                            //show connection error


                        } else {

                            visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                            totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager
                                    .getItemCount();
                            firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager
                                    .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                            if (loading) {
                                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {

                                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                                    page++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!loading
                                    && (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount) {
                                page++;
                                // call pagination and pass page limit
                                 getPagination();

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: code is fine to understand,what is loading here?

Comment: Loading is the flag which is checking that api or data is loging currently or not.

Answer (score 0):

In `API url` take a `parameter` `count`, whenever `getPagination()` method is called you can send increased value in `count` `parameter`. According to that  `count` parameter on server side you can add logic to get next items.

**See how to pass parameter in Api using volley**

```
StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
     "http://196.1.1.1/myurl",
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String Response) {
                  // get response
         }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
}){@Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams(){
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
      params.put("Count", count);
      return mParams;
 }
  }; 
Volley.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(strreq);
```

**Hope this will help.**

Comment: Sir, that is problem , how i can send the next page number to server side

Comment: I have also mentioned my getPagination method above. and here     "http:/xyz/AppApi/ViewAllLatestProducts?UserName=wkappserviceuser&Password=q3j5tw4gtw6z2n92&Page=1"

Answer (score 0):

## Call the next page at the end of scroll.

You can determine when the recycler view is scrolled to the last element. And then you can send a request for the next page. When the next page returns new results add them in the previous result set and update the list.

[image]

## More explanation with RecyclerView

[How to implement pagination in RecyclerView on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955146/how-to-implement-pagination-in-recyclerview-on-scroll/62161731#62161731)

### Demo Project

[Github Link](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/RecyclerViewPagination)

[image]