# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I was following this page [Adding items to Endless Scroll RecyclerView with ProgressBar at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681905/adding-items-to-endless-scroll-recyclerview-with-progressbar-at-bottom/30691092#30691092) and I think I did everything right, but for some reason I get back on this line `onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();`

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)' on a null object reference
```

I know that there are a lot of posts regarding the null pointer error, but that line is in a if statement and it shouldn't be executed if it's null.

```
if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
```

Why is this happening ? What code should I post to help figuring out the problem ?

```
mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new MyAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add progress item
                myDataset.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myDataset.size() - 1);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //remove progress item
                        myDataset.remove(myDataset.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(myDataset.size());
                        MyRecyclerItems gridItem= new MyRecyclerItems();
                        gridItem.setAbout("Test");
                        gridItem.setEmail("tesssst@gmail.com");
                        myDataset.add(0,gridItem);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myDataset.size());
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                    }
                }, 2000);
                System.out.println("load");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out the `onLoadMoreListener` field is not null based on the if statement. What you didn't include however is the code being executed inside the `onLoadMore()` method.

From the partial stack trace you are trying the call `postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)` on a `Handler` inside the `onLoadMore()` method and said `Handler` has not been initialized (is null).

Comment: I posted the setOnLoadMoreListener. What do I have to initialize ?

Comment: You need to initialize the `handler` field variable. The SO post you linked is incomplete and a modification of another SO post (linked in the OP), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044449/put-an-indeterminate-progressbar-as-footer-in-a-recyclerview-grid/28090719#comment49412644_28090719 As you'll see in Vilen Melkumyan's answer they are initializing the `handler` variable in the `Activity.onCreate()`

Comment: I followed both of them but I have no idea how I missed that. Many thanks

Comment: am also fallowing this url https://github.com/kprathap23/Android/blob/master/EndlessRecyclerView/app/src/main/res/layout/wallpaper_activity.xml from there also sample only initially loading data only and then when i scroll up or down next hit not done.please help me appriciate it makes too late for me

Answer (score 11):

This error means handler is null.

Just initialize handler object before calling post method like this:

```
handler=new Handler();
```

Comment: you save my day. Thanks